# Copy data from Data Lake Storage to Database present in azure Analysis server using copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services

Is there any way to copy the data from azure data lake storage to database present in azure analysis server using azure data factory ? 
 I am trying to use copy activity to do the same task but I don't know how to specify the Analysis Server Database as the destination in output dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For the data connector not in data factory support list, you can write custom activity to access your data 
Here is the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities

Thanks,
Charles